# Data loss while writing from Spark Databricks to Azure Cosmos db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, databricks

I am sending dataframes from databricks to a graph collection present in azure cosmos db using azure cosmos spark connector and write configuration provided at https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark . But I am facing data loss while this data transfer occurs. I tried to write 800k records but there was a loss of 25k records. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Couple of things to check, what is the RU on the collection you are trying to insert the data in? Is there any throttling happening on the collection? What error you receive? You can check many of these things on the portal -> click Metrics under Monitoring section.

Comment: Used throughput is 100k RU/s and there is no error received.
Checked metrics too but didn't found anything useful